# SQL: Count Records if All Columns Are Equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I need to count only those order numbers where all products' status is **Active**.

Existing records:

```
OrderNo     ProductID     Status
1           1             Active
1           2             Active
1           3             Active
2           1             Inactive
2           2             Inactive
3           3             Active
4           1             Inactive
4           3             Active
```

Output:

```
Completed
2
```

Note: Both OrderNo 1 and 3 have product/s with Active status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
 (
   SELECT OrderNo
   FROM products
   GROUP BY OrderNo
   HAVING MIN(Status) = 'Active' AND MAX(Status) = 'Active'
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I like it's simplicity. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To get the total orders with active numbers

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE OrderNo NOT IN (SELECT * FROM products WHERE Status = 'Inactive' GROUP BY OrderNo)) as tmp_b; OrderNo
```

To get only the order numbers

```
SELECT OrderNo FROM 
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE OrderNo NOT IN (SELECT * FROM products WHERE Status = 'Inactive' GROUP BY OrderNo)) as tmp_b;
```

Comment: Downvote removed, but I think the OP wants you to print the OrderNr instead of the count

Comment: @Andomar I want to display the number of active order numbers.

Comment: Yep, every derived table needs an alias.  I'll fix that.

Comment: 2nd query returns '4' also.

Answer (score 1):

```
select   distinct OrderNo
from     Products p1
where    not exists
         (
         select  *
         from    Products p2
         where   p1.OrderNo = p2.OrderNo
                 and p2.Status = 'Active'
         )
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16641/6/0)

Comment: Need to group by orderno.

Comment: @Joe: Answer rewritten now (without a group by though)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Active` and `Inactive` are the only choices:

```
select Count( distinct OrderNo )
  from Products as OuterP
  where not exists ( select 42 from Products where OrderNo = OuterP.OrderNo and Status = 'Inactive' )
```

An index on `OrderNo` ascending/`Status` descending should make this fairly quick.

Comment: The query should return the list of order numbers for orders without an active product (not the count)

Comment: @Andomar - The title says "Count", the question says "count", the sample data shows a count. Even the comment "@Andomar I want to display the number of active order numbers." leads me to believe the OP wants a count. What, pray tell, have I missed?

Comment: I see your point, the question can definitely be read that way.  My comment was based on the example data.  It shows `2`, which is the only order number without an active product.  The count of those orders would have been `1`.

Comment: @Andomar - The comment after the sample result is: "Note: Both OrderNo 1 and 3 have product/s with Active status.", i.e. the `2` is the count of orders for which _all_ products are `Active`. First sentence of the question: "I need to count only those order numbers where all products' status is **Active**.". Order `2` is the only one which has _no_ `Active` products, while order `4` is mixed.